# Lagged dependent variables, bias and consistency

Tags: time-series, econometrics, bias, lags, consistency

I am working through Christopher Dougherty's Introduction to Econometrics, and am struggling to fully grasp the consequences of lagged dependent variables in terms of bias and consistency.

The key assumption appears to be that: the disturbance term in the regression is distributed independently of the regressors. In the context of time series models, this is separated out into two statements:

1. The disturbance terms is distributed independently of the values of the regressor in the same observation
2. The disturbance terms is distributed independently of the values of the regressor in the other observations

From what I can see, if (2) is violated then estimators will be biased, but are asymptotically consistent. If (1) is also violated, then the estimators will biased and inconsistent.

I can't understand *why* this distinction arises. For example, if the model is:

$ Y_{t} = \beta_{1} + \beta_{2} \cdot Y_{t-1} + u_{t}$

then with no autocorrelation, we can estimate $ \beta_{2}$ as:

$\widehat{\beta}_{2} = \beta_{2} + \frac{\widehat{\sigma}_{Y_{t-1}u_{t}}}{\widehat{\sigma}_{Y_{t-1}}^{2}}$

In other words, the true variable plus the ratio between the sample covariance of $Y_{t-1}$ and $u_{t}$ and the sample variance of $Y_{t-1}$.

When taking the expected value of $\widehat{\beta}_{2}$ to test for bias, we can't decompose this ratio, because the disturbance term will be correlated with future values of the regressor. So therefore, we can conclude that the estimator will be biased.

However, if we take asymptotic limits, the sample covariances and variances tend to the population covariances. The population covariance $\sigma_{Y_{t-1}u_{t}}$ is zero, since Y_{t-1} is generated before u_{t}.

This seems to rest on the fact that (1) is true but (2) is false, which seems to mean that:

- the covariance between the lagged dependent variable and the disturbance term is zero, but
- the expected value of the sample covariance between the lagged dependent variable and the disturbance term is not zero.
- alternatively, is it because the expected value of the ratio $\frac{\widehat{\sigma}_{Y_{t-1}u_{t}}}{\widehat{\sigma}_{Y_{t-1}}^{2}}$ is non-zero, or at least we can't analytically analyse it any further?

Have I understood this distinction correctly? If so, why are these statements true?

(Also, is it the case that if there was autocorrelation in the disturbance, then (1) above would be false and the covariance would be non-zero - so the estimator would also be inconsistent?)

Comment: I think in the process of writing the question, I have figured out the answer. When taking the expectation of a fraction, we can't decompose it into the separate expectations of the numerator and the denominator. If we split up the summation in the sample covariance, then each individual term is correlated with the sample variance (since the sample variance depends on all values of the regressor).